# In Git for xml '<' replaced with '&lt;'

Tags: git

When I checkin my xml file , '<' is replaced with & lt; . I can see it in the diff. I am in linux box and core.autocrlf=input for git settings. Do i need to modify any other settings, to avoid this change from happening ?

Comment: Not something you would normally expect from git. What does `git diff` show before you check in? What do you use to check in?

Comment: Do you have any hooks set up? Is there a `.gitattributes` file somewhere?

Comment: git add "file path". git commit -m 'Comments'  and git push. In gerrit when i see the difference , i see the above problem.

Comment: yes i have .gitattributes file in the base dir of my repo